# Redactor WYSIWYG root element p tag

Tags: wysiwyg, redactor

I'm using Redactor and it keep adding a <p> tag around the content of the wysiwyg. Does anyone know a way to disable this ?

Source: http://imperavi.com/redactor/

Comment: So did you sort that out?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#redactor').redactor({ paragraphy: false });
```